# why my method affects the class only inside the method?

Tags: python, class, methods

I have a few classes that use one another: Lanes is a property of Directions, Directions is a property of Diagram.
This is a method in Diagram class, it supposes to 'push' information from a list (phsr_lst) to Diagram -> Directions -> Lanes.
When I print the data I pushed using getattr(key_lan, cur_arrow) right after setattr(), I get the right data, but when printing it outside the method, it shows as if nothing was changed.
When I checked the memory address inside and outside the method, I got different addresses;

This is not the only method that I have that does the same thing - and works, although I did have the same problem with other methods. To be honest, I have no idea how I managed to solve it on the other ones ; I tried to change it to be almost the same but it still doesn't work.

```py
    def push_arrows(self):
        all_arrows = (self.phsr_lst[2], self.phsr_lst[5])
        lanes_list = (self.NO.LAN, self.SO.LAN, self.EA.LAN, self.WE.LAN)
        for arrow in all_arrows:
            for key_lan in lanes_list:
                orig_lanes = ("SR","RL","A","L","TL","T","TR","R")
                for cur_lan in orig_lanes:
                    if len(arrow) != 0:
                        cur_arrow = cur_lan + str(all_arrows.index(arrow))
                        setattr(key_lan, cur_arrow, arrow[0])
                        arrow.pop(0)
        self.phsr_lst[2] = []
        self.phsr_lst[12] = []
        self.phsr_lst[5] = []
```

**Main and Diagram class:**

```py
    from Directions import *
    
    
    class Diagram:
        """
          A class used to represent counting for different routes
        """
    
        def __init__(self):
            self.__North = Direction("North")
            self.__South = Direction("South")
            self.__East = Direction("East")
            self.__West = Direction("West")
            self.__InfoFromPhaser = []
    
        @property
        def NO(self):
            """Get the north info"""
            return self.__North
    
        @NO.setter
        def NO(self, value):
            """Set the north info"""
            self.__North = value
    
        @property
        def SO(self):
            """Get the south info"""
            return self.__South
    
        @SO.setter
        def SO(self, value):
            """Set the south info"""
            self.__South = value
    
        @property
        def EA(self):
            """Get the east info"""
            return self.__East
    
        @EA.setter
        def EA(self, value):
            """Set the east info"""
            self.__East = value
    
        @property
        def WE(self):
            """Get the west info"""
            return self.__West
    
        @WE.setter
        def WE(self, value):
            """Set the north info"""
            self.__West = value
    
        @property
        def phsr_lst(self):
            """Get the phaser list info"""
            return self.__InfoFromPhaser
    
        @phsr_lst.setter
        def phsr_lst(self, value):
            """Set the phaser list info"""
            self.__InfoFromPhaser = value
    
        def push_vol(self):
            vol_list = [self.phsr_lst[1], self.phsr_lst[11]]
            directions_mor = [self.NO.MOR, self.SO.MOR, self.EA.MOR, self.WE.MOR]
            directions_eve = [self.NO.EVE, self.SO.EVE, self.EA.EVE, self.WE.EVE]
            count = -1
            for vol in vol_list:
                count += 1
                if count == 0:
                    directions = directions_mor
                else:
                    directions = directions_eve
                for direc in directions:
                    routes = ["R", "T", "L"]
                    for rou in routes:
                        if vol:
                            setattr(direc, rou, vol[0])
                            vol.pop(0)
            self.phsr_lst[1] = []
            self.phsr_lst[11] = []
    
        def push_arrows(self):
            all_arrows = (self.phsr_lst[2], self.phsr_lst[5])
            lanes_list = (self.NO.LAN, self.SO.LAN, self.EA.LAN, self.WE.LAN)
            for arrow in all_arrows:
                for key_lan in lanes_list:
                    orig_lanes = ("SR", "RL", "A", "L", "TL", "T", "TR", "R")
                    for cur_lan in orig_lanes:
                        if len(arrow) != 0:
                            cur_arrow = cur_lan + str(all_arrows.index(arrow))
                            setattr(key_lan, cur_arrow, arrow[0])
                            arrow.pop(0)
            self.phsr_lst[2] = []
            self.phsr_lst[12] = []
            self.phsr_lst[5] = []
            self.phsr_lst[15] = []
    
    
    JUNC_Diagram = Diagram()
    JUNC_Diagram.phsr_lst = ['Morning', [44, 120, 46, 42, 178, 104, 34, 404, 49, 147, 703, 199],
                             [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                             [1800, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 120, 25, 4, 1, 0],
                             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                             0.49333333333333335, 666.0,
                             {'AErt': 219.0, 'AEt': 219.0, 'AWrt': 275.0, 'AWt': 275.0, 'BNl': 46.0, 'BNrt': 82.0,
                              'BNt': 82.0, 'CSl': 104.0, 'CSrt': 110.0, 'CStl': 110.0, 'DEl': 49.0, 'DWl': 49.0,
                              'EWl': 150.0, 'EWrt': 150.0, 'EWt': 150.0, 'imageA': 275.0, 'imageB': 82.0, 'imageC': 110.0,
                              'imageD': 49.0, 'imageE': 150.0, 'imageF': 0.0}, 1800, 'Evening',
                             [25, 165, 24, 44, 343, 237, 12, 113, 24, 115, 220, 106],
                             [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                             [1800, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 120, 25, 4, 1, 0],
                             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                             0.38142857142857145, 534.0,
                             {'ASl': 208.0, 'ASrt': 208.0, 'AStl': 208.0, 'BNl': 24.0, 'BNrt': 95.0, 'BNt': 95.0,
                              'CWl': 106.0, 'CWrt': 167.0, 'CWt': 168.0, 'DEl': 24.0, 'DErt': 62.0, 'DEt': 63.0,
                              'imageA': 208.0, 'imageB': 95.0, 'imageC': 168.0, 'imageD': 63.0, 'imageE': 0.0,
                              'imageF': 0.0}, 1800, ['Elsa', 'David', 'Sophie', 'Golda']]
    
    # The method that doesn't work
    JUNC_Diagram.push_arrows()
    
    # The method that doesn't works
    print("JUNC_Diagram.NO.LAN.T[0]", JUNC_Diagram.NO.LAN.T[0])
    print("JUNC_Diagram.NO.LAN.TR[0]", JUNC_Diagram.NO.LAN.TR[0])
    print("JUNC_Diagram.NO.LAN.L[0]", JUNC_Diagram.NO.LAN.L[0])
    print("JUNC_Diagram.SO.LAN.TL[0]", JUNC_Diagram.SO.LAN.TL[0])
    print("JUNC_Diagram.SO.LAN.L[0]", JUNC_Diagram.SO.LAN.L[0])
    
    # Different method that works
    JUNC_Diagram.push_vol()
    print(JUNC_Diagram.NO.MOR.L)
    print(JUNC_Diagram.NO.MOR.R)
    print(JUNC_Diagram.NO.MOR.T)
    print(JUNC_Diagram.SO.MOR.L)
    print(JUNC_Diagram.SO.MOR.R)
    print(JUNC_Diagram.SO.MOR.T)
```

**Direction class:**

```py
    from Routes import *
    from Lanes import *
    
    
    class Direction:
        """
          A class used to represent a direction containing it's counts and lanes
        """
    
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.__Morning_route = Routes()
            self.__Evening_route = Routes()
            self.__All_lanes = Lanes()
            self.__Name = name
            self.__Position_Specs = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    
        @property
        def MOR(self):
            """Get the morning info"""
            return self.__Morning_route
    
        @MOR.setter
        def MOR(self, value):
            """Set the morning info"""
            self.__Morning_route = value
    
        @property
        def EVE(self):
            """Get the evening info"""
            return self.__Evening_route
    
        @EVE.setter
        def EVE(self, value):
            """Set the evening info"""
            self.__Evening_route = value
    
        @property
        def LAN(self):
            """Get the lanes info"""
            return self.__All_lanes
    
        @LAN.setter
        def LAN(self, value):
            """Set the lanes info"""
            self.__All_lanes = value
    
        @property
        def NAME(self):
            """Get the name of the direction"""
            return self.__Name
    
        @NAME.setter
        def NAME(self, value):
            """Set the name of the direction"""
            self.__Name = value
    
        def empty_direction(self):
            return self.LAN.Empty_lanes() == self.MOR.Empty_routes() == self.EVE.Empty_routes()
    
        @property
        def POS(self):
            """Get the Position of the direction on the slide of the presentation"""
            return self.__Position_Specs
    
        @POS.setter
        def POS(self, value):
            """Set the Position of the direction on the slide of the presentation"""
            self.__Position_Specs = value
```

**Routes class:**

```py
    class Routes:
        """
          A class used to represent the counting of a route with right, left and through
        """
    
        def __init__(self, left=0, right=0, through=0):
            self.__left = left
            self.__right = right
            self.__through = through
    
        @property
        def L(self):
            """Get the left count"""
            return self.__left
    
        @L.setter
        def L(self, value):
            """Set the left count"""
            self.__left = value
    
        @property
        def R(self):
            """Get the right count"""
            return self.__right
    
        @R.setter
        def R(self, value):
            """Set the right count"""
            self.__right = value
    
        @property
        def T(self):
            """Get the through count"""
            return self.__through
    
        @T.setter
        def T(self, value):
            """Set the through count"""
            self.__through = value
    
        def Empty_routes(self):
            """returns if there are no volumes for the spesific route"""
            all_routes = [self.L, self.T, self.R]
            return sum(all_routes) == 0
```

**Lanes class:**

```py
    class Lanes:
        """
          A class used to represent the lanes of the counter, divided to [regular, p_transport] for each lane.
        """
    
        def __init__(self):
            self.__Separated_Right = [0, 0]
            self.__Right_Left = [0, 0]
            self.__All = [0, 0]
            self.__Left = [0, 0]
            self.__Through_Left = [0, 0]
            self.__Through = [0, 0]
            self.__Through_Right = [0, 0]
            self.__Right = [0, 0]
    
        @property
        def SR(self):
            """Get the Separated_Right lanes"""
            return self.__Separated_Right
    
        @SR.setter
        def SR(self, value):
            """Set the Separated_Right lanes"""
            self.__Separated_Right = value
    
        @property
        def RL(self):
            """Get the Right_Left lanes"""
            return self.__Right_Left
    
        @RL.setter
        def RL(self, value):
            """Set the Right_Left lanes"""
            self.__Right_Left = value
    
        @property
        def A(self):
            """Get the All lanes"""
            return self.__All
    
        @A.setter
        def A(self, value):
            """Set the All lanes"""
            self.__All = value
    
        @property
        def L(self):
            """Get the left lanes"""
            return self.__Left
    
        @L.setter
        def L(self, value):
            """Set the left lanes"""
            self.__Left = value
    
        @property
        def TL(self):
            """Get the Through_left lanes"""
            return self.__Through_Left
    
        @TL.setter
        def TL(self, value):
            """Set the Through_left lanes"""
            self.__Through_Left = value
    
        @property
        def T(self):
            """Get the Through lanes"""
            return self.__Through
    
        @T.setter
        def T(self, value):
            """Set the Through lanes"""
            self.__Through = value
    
        @property
        def TR(self):
            """Get the Through_Right lanes"""
            return self.__Through_Right
    
        @TR.setter
        def TR(self,  value):
            """Set the Through_Right lanes"""
            self.__Through_Right = value
    
        @property
        def R(self):
            """Get the Right lanes"""
            return self.__Right
    
        @R.setter
        def R(self,  value):
            """Set the Right lanes"""
            self.__Right =  value
```

Comment: You'll get a lot more help if you post code that people can simply
copy/paste/run, please take a look at this
[page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I tried to use the setasttr() with a specific cell (among other problems and mistakes I had...)
To fix it, I created the array and then used the setattr() for the whole array and not a specific cell.
This is the new function with the changes:

```py
def push_arr2(self):
    arr_list = [self.phsr_lst[2], self.phsr_lst[5]]
    SR_cur_arrow_input = [0, 0]
    orig_lanes = ["R", "TR", "T", "TL", "L", "A", "RL"]
    directions = [self.NO.LAN, self.SO.LAN, self.EA.LAN, self.WE.LAN]
    for direc in directions:
        for lan in orig_lanes:
            if arr_list[0]:
                cur_arrow_input = [arr_list[0][0], arr_list[1][0]]
                if lan == "R" and arr_list[0][0] == 9:
                    SR_cur_arrow_input = [0, 0]
                    SR_cur_arrow_input[0] = 1
                    cur_arrow_input[0] = 0
                if lan == "R" and arr_list[1][0] == 9:
                    SR_cur_arrow_input[1] = 1
                    cur_arrow_input[1] = 0
                setattr(direc, lan, cur_arrow_input)
                setattr(direc, "SR", SR_cur_arrow_input)
                arr_list[0].pop(0)
                arr_list[1].pop(0)
    self.phsr_lst[12] = []
    self.phsr_lst[15] = []
```